# How do you remove an isolated number from a string in R?

Tags: r, regex, gsub, stringr

This is a silly question, but I can't seem to find a solution in R online. I am trying to remove an isolated number from a long string. For example, I would like to remove the number 27198 from the sentence below.

```
x <- "hello3 my name 27198 is 5joey"
```

I tried the following:

```
gsub("[0-9]","",x)
```

Which results in:

```
"hello my name  is joey"
```

But I want:

```
"hello3 my name is 5joey"
```

This seems really simple, but I am not well versed with regular expressions. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can specify word boundary (`\\b`) at the end of one or more digits (`[0-9]+`)

```
gsub("\\b[0-9]+\\b", "", x)
#[1] "hello3 my name  is 5joey"
```